# Community version of Visual Paradigm has disabled code generation

Tags: java, eclipse, diagrams, uml

I've succesfully integrated Visual Paradigm - Community edition in Eclipse (Kepler). I used [this tutorial](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/tutorials/eclipseuml.jsp), the problem is that when I created the class in modeling tool, the button "Update code" is disabled. Also when I want to create a diagram object from existing code, the button "Update UML Model" is also disabled.

When I right-click on created class in "Diagram navigation", and select "Update to code", I get "Failed to generate code. java.lang.NullPointerException"

Is this option disabled in community edition? I've only found that in community edition you can create only one Class diagram without watermarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found [here](http://forums.visual-paradigm.com/posts/list/291078.html#796342) that it's not supported.